# Perl and Process Management

Tags: perl, memory, process, parallel-processing, ipc

I'm working on a pretty big enterprise application using Perl, has tens of modules, etc, which mainly used to crawl some stuff over the web.

One of the subroutines I wrote, is doing an image retrieval & analysis. Usually it takes couple of seconds to accomplish, for each parameter I sent to it. So I'm sending it to a different process (forking...). The issue is, after some time the system becomes very unstable, memory filled up.

**Questions**:

1. Is it because each process created, creates a copy of the parent data in a separate memory location? if so, does it mean each child has a copy of ALL the modules? (and there are tens...)
2. What is the best approach to free this memory / manage these processes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forking uses [copy-on-write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write), so forked processes shouldn't grab too much memory unless they are especially long-lived.

It sounds like you've got a memory leak in your system. Do you have any mutually-recursive dependencies or circular data structures? If so, you may want to look into using [Scalar::Util::weaken](https://metacpan.org/module/Scalar::Util) to tweak reference-counts on your data structures.

Comment: I will look into it, also, I exit the processes in each child using 'exit 0' without any sig handler, later when I check ps, I see lots of perl zombie processes, many many many, even tens / hundredths of them, is it normal?

Comment: You need to [wait](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/waitpid.html) on your child processes to receive their exit status, or they will live on as zombies. You might want to look into something like [Parallel::ForkManager](https://metacpan.org/module/Parallel::ForkManager) which handles these details for you.